# Why don't we need to extract values from Result in some rust iterators?

Tags: rust

Here, I have a simple map and sum over an iterator:

```rust
fn main() {
    let s = "
aoeu
aoeu
aoeu
aoeu
";

    let ls = s.lines();
    let i: usize = ls.map(|l| l.len()).sum();
    dbg!(i);
}
```

This compiles and runs fine. When I look at the [source for `lines`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/src/std/io/mod.rs.html#2250), the `next` method returns `Option<Result<String>>`.

But the map above calls `.len()` directly on each item. I understand the value is extracted from inside the `Option` (a `None` value would mean the end of the iterator). Is `.len()` being called on the `Result` object? Why don't we need to call something like `map()`* to extract the value from `Result`?

Thanks!

* I had thought `Result::map` had a different meaning to `Iterator::map`, but maybe I'm confusing myself...

Comment: [Wrong `Lines`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/src/core/str/mod.rs.html#1324-1336)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[There are two `lines` in the standard library.](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/index.html?search=lines)

The [one on `str`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.str.html#method.lines), which returns [`std::str::Lines`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/str/struct.Lines.html), which is an iterator of `&str`. This is the one you are using. Splitting a string cannot fail, so it doesn't need to use `Result`.

And the [one on `std::io::BufRead`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/trait.BufRead.html#method.lines), which returns [`std::io::Lines`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/struct.Lines.html). This one reads from a `BufRead`, which can fail (eg. reading a file on a network drive can fail if the drive becomes unreachable), so it must return a `Result`.